# Задание таймера обратного отсчета

Tags: javascript, setinterval, settimeout, таймер

Нужно, чтобы при получении чисел, которые указывает пользователь, они переводили своё значение в таймер. Но проблема не в этом. Когда таймер доходит до нуля (секундный), то минута должна минусоваться, а секундный таймер обнуляться, и заново от 59, и так до конца. Но почему-то когда он доходит до нуля, он не обнуляется (идет по отрицательным значениям), а минута не делает -1.

```
    //for_break_functions
function toBreak(){
var to_break = document.getElementsByClassName("digit");
if(to_break[0].innerHTML !== 0) 
to_break[0].innerHTML--; 
}
function toBreakPlus(){
var to_break = document.getElementsByClassName("digit");
to_break[0].innerHTML++;
}


$(".minus").click(function() { 
 toBreak();
});
$(".plus").click(function() {
  toBreakPlus();
});
//for_break_functions_end

//for_session_functions
function toBreak2(){
var to_break = document.getElementsByClassName("digit2");
if(to_break[0].innerHTML !== 0) 
to_break[0].innerHTML--; 
}
function toBreakPlus2(){
var to_break = document.getElementsByClassName("digit2");
to_break[0].innerHTML++;
}


$(".minus2").click(function() { 
 toBreak2();
});
$(".plus2").click(function() {
  toBreakPlus2();
});



  function foo() {
  var obj_time1 = document.getElementById("seconds"),      
      obj_digit = document.getElementsByClassName("digit2"),
      obj_time2 = document.getElementById("minutes");
    obj_time1.innerHTML = 59;
    obj_time2.innerHTML = obj_digit[0].innerHTML - 1;
      var timerId = setInterval(function() {
      obj_time1.innerHTML--;
}, 1000);

    if(obj_time1.innerHTML == 0) {
      obj_time2.innerHTML--;
      clearInterval(timerId);
      obj_time1.innerHTML = 59;
      timerId = setInterval(function() {
      obj_time1.innerHTML--;
}, 1000);
    }

  //   if(obj_time1.innerHTML === 0){
  //   obj_time2.innerHTML--;
  //   obj_time1.innerHTML = 59;
  // }
  }
foo();
```

//html

```
<body>
  <center>
    <p>
      <h2>BREAK LENGTH</h2>
      <button class = "minus">-</button>
      <span class = "digit" style = "padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; font-size: 66px;">5</span>
      <button class = "plus">+</button>
    </p>
    <img src = "https://services.garmin.com/appsLibraryBusinessServices_v0/rest/apps/4b11ad8f-3e48-4112-83df-336065c49829/icon/d31ca7be-0497-4370-801f-97a29dc3b584" class = "pomodor">
  <div class = "time"><span id="minutes"></span><span>:</span><span id = "seconds"></span></div>
  <div style = "margin-top: 400px; margin-left: 34px;">
  <h2>SESSION LENGTH</h2>
    <div style = "margin-left: -15px">
          <button class = "minus2">-</button>
      <span class = "digit2" style = "padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; font-size: 66px;">25</span>
      <button class = "plus2">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </center>
    </body>
```

//css

```
body {
  background-color: #696969;
}
.pomodor{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -190px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
.time{
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 210px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-left: 800px;
}
```

Comment: Первое что бросается в глаза... в if стоит проверка не значения "внутри" innerHTML. Плюс, не стоит использовать innerHTML для "счета" данных. Почему не создать переменную, которая будет подставляться в html?

Comment: @NeedHate Пофиксил, но все равно ничего не изменилось

Comment: Приведите полный код, включая html/css разметку

Comment: @Cheg  Добавил код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ваше условие `if (obj_time1.innerHTML == 0)` нужно поместить внутрь
   `setInterval()`, иначе получается, что оно срабатывает только
   единожды, при самом запуске `foo()`.
2. И само условие `if (obj_time1.innerHTML == 0)` неверное - вы 1
   секунду теряете таким образом. Нужно так - `if (obj_time1.innerHTML < 0)`.
3. Весь код пересчета секунд и минут нужно вынести в отдельную функцию,
   например, `start()` и зациклить ее в `setInterval()` - тогда все
   будет считаться как надо.

Рабочий пример (кол-во секунд в минуте установил на `3`, чтобы не ждать целую минуту для проверки):

```js
//for_break_functions
function toBreak() {
  var to_break = document.getElementsByClassName("digit");
  if (to_break[0].innerHTML !== 0)
    to_break[0].innerHTML--;
}

function toBreakPlus() {
  var to_break = document.getElementsByClassName("digit");
  to_break[0].innerHTML++;
}


$(".minus").click(function() {
  toBreak();
});
$(".plus").click(function() {
  toBreakPlus();
});
//for_break_functions_end

//for_session_functions
function toBreak2() {
  var to_break = document.getElementsByClassName("digit2");
  if (to_break[0].innerHTML !== 0)
    to_break[0].innerHTML--;
}

function toBreakPlus2() {
  var to_break = document.getElementsByClassName("digit2");
  to_break[0].innerHTML++;
}


$(".minus2").click(function() {
  toBreak2();
});
$(".plus2").click(function() {
  toBreakPlus2();
});



function foo() {
  var obj_time1 = document.getElementById("seconds"),
    obj_digit = document.getElementsByClassName("digit2"),
    obj_time2 = document.getElementById("minutes"),
    timerId;
  obj_time1.innerHTML = 3;
  obj_time2.innerHTML = obj_digit[0].innerHTML;
  timerId = setInterval(function() {
    start();
  }, 1000);

  function start() {
    obj_time1.innerHTML--;

    if (obj_time1.innerHTML < 0) {
      obj_time2.innerHTML--;
      clearInterval(timerId);
      obj_time1.innerHTML = 3;
      timerId = setInterval(function() {
        start();
      }, 1000);

    }
  }

  //   if(obj_time1.innerHTML === 0){
  //   obj_time2.innerHTML--;
  //   obj_time1.innerHTML = 59;
  // }
}
foo();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #696969;
}

.pomodor {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -190px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.time {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 210px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-left: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
  <p>
    <h2>BREAK LENGTH</h2>
    <button class="minus">-</button>
    <span class="digit" style="padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; font-size: 66px;">5</span>
    <button class="plus">+</button>
  </p>
  <img src="https://services.garmin.com/appsLibraryBusinessServices_v0/rest/apps/4b11ad8f-3e48-4112-83df-336065c49829/icon/d31ca7be-0497-4370-801f-97a29dc3b584" class="pomodor">
  <div class="time"><span id="minutes"></span><span>:</span><span id="seconds"></span></div>
  <div style="margin-top: 400px; margin-left: 34px;">
    <h2>SESSION LENGTH</h2>
    <div style="margin-left: -15px">
      <button class="minus2">-</button>
      <span class="digit2" style="padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; font-size: 66px;">25</span>
      <button class="plus2">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</center>
```

И еще рекуомендую вам дописать код так, чтобы он тормозил таймер, когда `obj_time1` и `obj_time2` равны 0.

Answer (score 0):

Пробуем вот такую реализацию таймера:
Важно, конечно, останавливать таймер, если оба значения "Минут" и "Секунд" меньше нуля и делать проверку. Так же делать проверку, чтобы значения не были выше 60 (по понятным причинам).

```js
let clocks = () => {
 let minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
 let seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");    
 let minutes_data = 0;
 let seconds_data = 5;
 
 let timer = setInterval(function() {
  minutes.innerHTML = minutes_data;
  seconds.innerHTML = seconds_data-- ;
  if(seconds_data < 10) { 
   seconds.innerHTML = '<span>0</span>' + seconds_data;
  }
  if(minutes_data < 10) {
   minutes.innerHTML = '<span>0</span>' + minutes_data;
  }
  if(seconds_data == 0) {
   seconds_data = 59;
   minutes_data--;
   if(minutes_data < 0) clearInterval(timer)
  }
 }, 1000);  
 
 }
 clocks();
```

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
}
body {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
 
 font-family: sans-serif;
 padding: 15%;
}
.timer {
 font-size: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="timer">
 <span id="minutes"></span> : <span id="seconds"></span>
</div>
```